# Mongoose syntax for updating an object inside an array within a Mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose's `findOneAndUpdate` to update a certain object within an array.  I was able to use Mongo's documentation to build some native code that works (in Robomongo, for example), but I am uncertain of the equivalent Mongoose syntax.

Here is my schema as coded with Express:

```
var NotesSchema = new Schema({
    NoteID: Number,
    Title: String,
    Items: [ { ItemID: Number, Title : String, DateCreated : Date, DateModified: Date, Checked: Boolean } ],
    DateCreated: Date,
    DateModified: Date
});
```

In this example, I want to update the `Title` of an `Item` inside the `Items` array.

Here is my Mongo code.  It references the array by getting the `NoteID`, then the `ItemID`, and then it sets the `Title` text.

```
db.notesmodels.update( 
    { NoteID : 29751527, "Items.ItemID" : 95373900 }, 
    { $set : { "Items.$.Title" : "Hello 777" } }
)
```

So the Mongoose code I want to build will take in `NoteID`, `ItemID` and `Title`.  How would I do that with `findOneAndUpdate`?  Alternatively, I could try to use native Mongo code within Express, but so far that hasn't worked either.

Comment: What "hasn't worked" stands for? Do you got some error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mongoose it should look something like this:

```
var Notes = mongoose.model('NotesSchema');

Notes.findOneAndUpdate(
    {   'NoteID': 29751527,
        'Items.ItemID': 95373900 
    },
    {   $set:{
            'Items.$.Title': 'Hello 777'
        }
    },
    function(err,result){
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

It will return modified document.